# How to make sure that all JSON fields are presented in a Swift Decodable model?

Tags: json, swift, codable, decodable

Let’s imagine a third-party JSON API returning a model like this:

```
{
  "key1": "Hello"
}
```

So we describe it as follows:

```
struct Model: Codable {
  var key1: String
}
```

Eventually the JSON model gets a new field…

```
{
  "key1": "Hello",
  "key2": {
    "key3": "World"
  }
}
```

…and the old `Model` still works, but it misses a new property `key2`.

Is there any way to verify that **all** JSON keys are presented in the Decodable model?

Comment: Parsing as dictionary instead of your object

Comment: So what do you want to do if not all the keys are decoded? Crash?

Comment: @emelagumat Could you elaborate? How does JSONSerialization help?

Comment: @Sweeper I’d prefer to throw an error.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? When the third party adds a field to their object it would break any version of your app that you already released for no reason.

Comment: @dan Thanks for asking. That’s correct, I want any old version of the app to stop working. To be more specific, if the `Model` is updated and POST-ed back after encoding, it can be unsafe for the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it by getting all the keys in the json message by using `JSONSerialization` and then comparing them to the key(s) in the parsed data using reflection

This code only compares the count, a more thorough check should verify each individual key

```
do {
    let dictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any]
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: data)
    if let keys = dictionary?.keys {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: result)
        if keys.count != mirror.children.count {
            print("Wrong number of keys") 
            //throw SomeError 
        } 
    }
    //handle result 
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is very close but I need a fully featured verification. How about nested models?

Comment: @Vadim Then you need to dig down into the `dictionary` (or whatever your root object is) and compare each sub-structure by itself. More messy but basically the same.

Comment: Ah, `Mirror` provides values which can be reflected as well. This works, thanks a lot!

Comment: Even better the `JSONSerialization` can be replaced by the `keyDecodingStrategy.custom`, to collect all the keys 